# Opinions: Starting Career in IT

Tags: software-industry, contracts, contractors, entry-level, fulltime

I'm a recent graduate and have been looking for my first full time job for  8 months.

I have little work experience which has been the main roadblock in my job search.

I recently got accepted into an IT Consultant company and have gotten an offer through this company that requires a 2 year commitment with heavy penalties for leaving before the 2 years.

- What are the advantages of taking a consulting position over a
  full-time perm job?
- Is it easier to find contract/consulting jobs than FT/Perm?
- What would some strategies be for a recent graduate to break into IT?
- What are some ways to overcome my lack of experience
- What are some pitfalls that a recent graduate should be wary of.

I am in the United States.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43717/discussion-on-question-by-mrmanny-opinions-starting-career-in-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a glorified placement company for IT positions. These have been around for a while but became kind of the thing for IT and developer jobs around ~2010 when IT jobs were in downturn.

Essentially, they put you through a training program, coding bootcamp etc... then you owe them 2 years of work to pay this "experience" off. The pay will be lower, because they are setting up contracts for jobs themselves and then paying you a smaller fee to do the work, because they are making money off of you.

It's true you do gain experience, real world knowledge because you will be working / contracting for real companies, but your experience will be cursory. You won't know or be privy to the business reasons why you are doing your task, you'll just have been pointed in a direction.

So in short, you will make less, and be stuck in a contract you can't break without paying.

Comment: This is really exploitation, thanks for the insight. Does it end up being worth it in the end? If I am able to put the work experience on my resume, will employers respect it?

Comment: I would think its not worth it. You got a CS degree, that's far more respectable than completing a program like this.